# beautiful and artistic book templates

Tags: templates

i am looking for repositories of very  beautiful and artistic latex book templates. this [question already appeared here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) 12 years ago. I am asking again because in 12 years, more templates repositories could be available.

by beautiful and artistic I mean designs that could compete with `[designrr][2]`(I don't want to spend US$ 300,00 for an atistic design template that does not support math equations!

Comment: If you don't want to spend money, create your own ... =)

Comment: @Humberto There is no need to ask this again. Even if the other question is 12 years old, it is still open and people can add new answers if there are new templates.

Comment: @jasper Habitch, By sharing knowledge and collaborating on projects, we can create truly innovative solutions that benefit everyone, regardless of their ability to pay.  sure if I have the sjills to create a template i would share not sell as I have done with math software I've programmed. iam studying design to better make free contents in several areas. I saw in your bio that you earn  money with latex templates but remember that the own latex project is a free sofware initiative.

Comment: @HumbertoJoséBortolossi I actually don't earn money with creating LaTeX templates and I totally endorse the idea of open source software. What I am paid for is the time I spend with typesetting and designing, which I believe is totally legit. I added my original comment in a jokingly way to point out that sophisticated solutions for templates using open software might be as costly as commercial solutions because of the work and time one has to invest.

Comment: @ 
Jasper Habicht
 I see your point. indeed  it is difficulty to find beautiful book templates even paying for them.